# What should an om component return to render nothing?

Tags: clojurescript, om

Is it possible to write a component that renders nothing, for example, if its cursor data is empty ?

I can not do

```
(defn count-or-nothing [list-cursor owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
       (if (not (empty? list-cursor))
         (dom/div nil "You have some elements !")))))
```

The if clause returns nil, which causes an error message

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render():
>   A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned null,
>   undefined, an array, or some other invalid object.

I got by, by rendering an empty span, but that sounds clumsy. 
Do I necessarily have to refactor my code and get the test "out" of this component ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding of why you cannot do this is because React needs to keep track of the component in the DOM and does this by adding a react-id attribute to the nodes.
If you render "nothing", then React doesn't know how to mount it into the DOM (its effectively unmounted). Since you can't have a mounted unmounted component, it doesn't allow this.

The *solution* would be to have the non-empty state be its own component and then have the PARENT conditionally build that component. That way, if you want to render nothing, it unmounts the component and.. renders nothing.

```
(defn something-interesting [list-cursor owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/div nil "You have some elements !"))))

(defn count-or-nothing [list-cursor owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/div nil
        ; Other UI stuff here maybe...
        (when-not (empty? list-cursor)
          (om/build something-interesting list-cursor))))))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was doing. I had not thought about the reactid justification, though. Thanks !

Comment: Note : this might change in the future, since apparently, React 0.11 allows returning null (http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#rendering-to-null) - haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @phtrivier tested on latest Om recently and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is : you can't do it.

I would mark this as a duplicate of [Unable to display two components in OM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448551/unable-to-display-two-components-in-om?rq=1)  , but there is no answer on this question...

[EDIT] Fixed the question link

Comment: hm, you would mark this question as a duplicate of itself?